# Angular CLI error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having an issue while installing Angular CLI.
I wrote a command on cmd prompt on Windows 10:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

The following error occurred:

> Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning ETIMEDOUT: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.25.35:443

Here is a picture of the situation:

[image]

Comment: Try `npm cache clear --force`. If that doesn't work, try removing the `package.json.lock` file, verify your npm cache with `npm cache verify` and then try to install angular again.

Comment: You're welcome. Which one made it work? Just doing the `npm cache clear --force` or did you have to remove the `.lock` file and verify the cache again?

Comment: DrZoo ...Just npm cache clear --force

Answer (score 0):

Running the command `npm cache clear --force` will usually solve this problem.

If `npm cache clear --force` does not solve the problem, you can try removing the `package.json.lock` file from your project, and then verify the npm cache again with the command `npm cache verify`.